# Asymtotic behavior of ratio of integrals (expectation of some random variable)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, expectation

From the Matlab numerical experiments, I could observe:

$$I(\theta)\equiv \frac{I_1(\theta)}{I_2(\theta)}\equiv \frac{\int_0^{\infty}x^k e^{\theta x-x^{1+k}}dx}{\int_0^{\infty}e^{\theta x-x^{1+k}}dx}$$

converges to a finite limit as $\theta\rightarrow \infty $ whenever $0<k<1$, whereas $I(\theta)$ diverges to infinity as $\theta\rightarrow \infty $ when $k\geq 1$. I really want to verify this observation analytically.

Notice that $I(\theta)=E[X^k]$, where $X$ has a probability density $$\frac{e^{\theta x-x^{1+k}}}{\int_0^{\infty}e^{\theta x-x^{1+k}}dx}$$ on the support $[0,\infty)$.

When $k=1$, $I(\theta)=E[X]$ is an expected value of truncated normal random variable on $[0,\infty)$. In particular, when $0<k<1$, the density decays slower than the normal density function.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: As you have mentioned, when $k=1$ your random variable is a truncated normal, with a mean that grows close to $\theta/2$ when $\theta\to\infty$, and so $I(\theta)=E[X|\theta]\to\infty$. Did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: Hi Thanks much for your comment. Yes, I want to show that if $k<1$ then $I(\theta)$ does converge as $\theta\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Oops, didn't read carefully, sorry